# Sending EditText data from one activity to other

Tags: c#, android, mono

I am new to Mono For Android and im trying to send one typed-text data from one EditText on activity1.cs to a TextView in another activity, but it doesnt work.
Here is the code:

this is the Activity1.cs:

```
    public string Item;

     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button AddButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AddButton);
        Button ViewButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ViewButton);
        EditText addNewAssignmentField = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addNewAssignmentField);


        AddButton.Click += delegate
        {
            if (addNewAssignmentField.Text == "")
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Please Write Assignment To Add", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Item = addNewAssignmentField.Text;//.ToString();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Assignment Added!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                addNewAssignmentField.Text = "";

             ShowMessage(Item); //ignore this

              }


        };

        ViewButton.Click += delegate
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(ViewListActivity));
        };
    }
```

This is the other activity:

```
     Activity1 ac1 = new Activity1();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "ListLayout" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ListLayout);
        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        var listItemsTxt = new TextView(this);
        EditText itemsList = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.itemsList);
        itemsList.Text = ac1.Item;
    }
```

the EditText on the other activity isnt getting the text from the EditText on the Activity1.cs

Thank You!

Comment: I don't know on mono but the way to do it is via intents, so I suggest you to Google for "android mono intent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass it through intents

In your first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putStringExtra("edit_text_content", myEditText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

In your second activity's `onCreate`

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("edit_text_content");
myEditText.setText(text);
```

Comment: Thank you! With a little bit of changes ive finally succeeded!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with assuming that you can create an instance of an `Activity` using `new`...

```
Activity1 ac1 = new Activity1();
```

...never try to do this, it won't work. Consequently this line...

```
itemsList.Text = ac1.Item;
```

...will never be a valid way to access data from another `Activity`.

The correct way to do this is to pass the data as an `extra` carried in an `Intent` which is used to start the second `Activity`.

I don't program using Mono - even though I'm originally a C# programmer, I decided to learn Java instead (they're massively similar anyway).

Translating (in my head) from how I'd do it in Java to how it should be done in Mono, try something like this...

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.SetClass(this, typeof(ViewListActivity));
i.PutExtra("TheItem", item);
StartActivity(i);
```

Then in the second `Activity`, something like the following in `onCreate(...)`...

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    ...
    Intent i = GetIntent();
    itemsList.Text = i.GetStringExtra("TheItem");
}
```

As I said, I'm not a Mono programmer so I may not have the syntax of methods correct but I hope that illustrates how to pass data from one `Activity` to another.

Comment: Thank you! But in the second activity ive used string and that worked.

Comment: @LStyle : Hmmm, OK. So I gave you an answer using Mono C# syntax which should have worked perfectly (even though I don't program with Mono) but you accepted an answer which was written in Java syntax. Sigh!

Comment: Your right, although I couldnt get that to work, so I tried the other method and it worked. I'll try your method now, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Ok ive finally succeeded!
This is the Working Code for other new users:
Activity 1.cs:

```
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.sendBtn);
        EditText editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            string username = editText.Text.ToString();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetClass(this, typeof(Activity2));
            intent.PutExtra("username", editText.Text);
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
    }
```

Activity2.cs:

```
public class Activity2 : Activity
{
    string itemContent;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
        var textView1 = new TextView(this);
        EditText editTxt = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTxt);
        itemContent = Intent.GetStringExtra("username");
        editTxt.Text = itemContent;
    }
}
```

Thank you all for helping me out!